# REST API call in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api

Hello I'm having trouble with calling rest api in ruby on rails app..
First of all, I just cannot get the basic idea of how to arrange the codes in the application, for which I've searched everywhere for some specific example but could not find anything useful. 
 It's a bank API used to make inquiry and transfers. I registered my temporary app domain, received the client ID key and secret key for the app. I set the callback URI to my app domain (ex. testapp.io ), and there are all sorts of REST sources provided for the API usage like GET /account/balance, GET /bank/status, GET /oauth/2.0/authorize, POST /transfer/deposit. 
 From here, I don't know how to utilize my API keys in the app, or how these REST sources should be applied. As far as I know, the API uses oauth2 for authorization, so I might need to install some gems for auth and uri opening.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'rest-client'

class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def index
    request_uri = "https://testapi.open-platform.or.kr/banks"
    buffer = open(request_uri).read
    @result = JSON.parse(buffer)

  end
end
```

This is what I did to try to open a source uri, and of course it returned access blocked message on the result. Am I even going the right direction on calling this? I really need some advice on setting and utilizing the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API should have endpoints to get an `access_token`, you should use your `client id key` and `secret key`  to get a token and then for each subsequent API calls you should include that token in the headers.

Rest client should be pretty easy to use to make a API call.

Comment: Does the token need to be reissued and included every time an API call is requested?

Comment: I think it'd be dependent on the API so you should explore the api docs but generally once the access token expires, there should be a way to get a `refresh token` which you use to refresh your `access token` or get a new one

Comment: Oh thank you Subash I think there is a refresh token. Rest should be easy to use if I ever get the hang of it, but the docs are not kind enough for a newbie like myself ^.T

Comment: @Rangdini no worries, glad to be of help, would you accept the answer if it answered your question